# Induction: $\frac1{1 \cdot 5} + \frac1{5 \cdot 9} + \cdots + \frac1{(4n-3)(4n+1)}$

Tags: induction

> For $n \ge 1$, let
>   $$a_n = \dfrac1{1 \cdot 5} + \dfrac1{5 \cdot 9} + \cdots + \dfrac1{(4n-3)(4n+1)}.$$
>   Guess a simple explicit formula for $a_n$ and prove it by induction.

Hi, I'm trying to answer this question. I was not provided with a solution.

Comment: Have you tried computing it for a few values of $n$ and tried to guess the pattern?

Comment: Im still keep trying but something is off everytime. i dont have much mathematical background so im really struggling with these kind of proofs. i was hoping to get a solution for this so i can see how i can tackle this problem. thanks

Comment: @arcadeboy Compute $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$. Edit them into your question.

Comment: Can someone show me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{4k-3}-\frac{1}{4k+1}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{9}+...+\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)=\frac{n}{4n+1}$$

Comment: seems like the formula? how would u prove it ?

Comment: @arcadeboy I proved it. See my proof.

Comment: What about all the steps like base case and stuff? sorry if im asking something stupid

Comment: @arcadeboy I fixed my post . See now.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at it now =)